# Which "end of round" effect resolves first: dealing in a dead player, or game end due to low honor?

Tags: ninja-burger

In Ninja Burger *("No matter how alert your guards, how deep your bunker, or how secure your office, we deliver in 30 minutes or less")*, one possible game end is if the average Honor of all players at the end of a round is less than 4. The winner is the player with the highest Honor at the time.  Also, if a player has zero Honor at the end of a round, they "apologize to their ancestors," draw a new ninja and a new hand, and restart with 6 honor.

Which of these effects happens first, since both just say "at end of round"? If a player's zero Honor brings the average low enough to trigger the game's end, but their new character with 6 Honor doesn't bring the average that low, does the game end or not?

(Bonus complication if you say "the game ends": if 6 Honor is enough to win the game at this point, does that mean the player who had zero Honor - but restarted with a new ninja that has 6 honor - wins? Or does the game end before that player can restart with a new ninja?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game ends, the player with zero honor doesn't get a new ninja until just before a new round starts, and only if the round hasn't ended. In the [rule book](http://www.sjgames.com/ninjaburger/rules.html) under **Phase 8: Check Honor**, besides the checks to see if the game has ended because a single player has 5 more honor than every other player, or the franchise honor is so high or low that the manager's position becomes open, it says this:

> If no one has won, a new round can start. **Before the round starts**, though, any ninjas whose Honor has gone to zero or less must make amends ...

Comment: Thanks, that's very clear. I was looking at the "You Have No Honor!" section right below it, which uses the more ambiguous "at the end of the round."